# jQuery dialog form in a html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog

I have a simple html form with submit button, which on clicking will go to action page1.php. I have a table inside this form. Now I want each row of the table provided with button to open the jquery dialog box on clicking. In this dialog user enters some details then press OK then that detail is copied to the corresponding row of that table.

The problem I am facing is, when i press the open dialog button then whole form is being submitted and page1.php is called. How do I differentiate the calls on both (submit and open dialog) buttons with the same form.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Validators/ClientSideValidator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/row.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-
ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<title>title</title>
<link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />


<script>

$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 1000
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 1000
  }
});

$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
});  

function PopulateDetails(wt,lng,wid,ht){
  document.getElementById("wt").value=wt;
  document.getElementById("lgt").value=lng;
  document.getElementById("wdt").value=wid;
  document.getElementById("ht").value=ht;
}
//onclick="CallDialog()"
function PopulateForm(){
 document.getElementById("weight" +      
document.getElementById("pkg").value).value=document.getElementById("wt").value;
 document.getElementById("length" +  
document.getElementById("pkg").value).value=document.getElementById("lgt").value;
 document.getElementById("width" +    
document.getElementById("pkg").value).value=document.getElementById("wdt").value;
 document.getElementById("height" +  
document.getElementById("pkg").value).value=document.getElementById("ht").value;  
 $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "close" );
}

function disappear(){
  document.getElementById("dialog").style.display = "hidden";
}

</script>


<form name="GetQuotesForm" action="page1.php" method="POST">

<div id="Body">
<table width="740" border="1">
<tr>
<font size="5">PARCEL DETAILS</font>
<TABLE id="dataTable0" width="740px" border="1">
  <TR>
   <TD width="30" align="center"><b> Pkg </b></TD>
   <TD width="171" align="center"><b> Weight (kg) </b></TD>
   <TD width="171" align="center"><b> Length (cm) </b></TD>
   <TD width="171" align="center"><b> Width (cm) </b></TD>
   <TD width="171" align="center"><b> Height (cm) </b></TD>
 <!--  <TD width="20" align="center"> Sel </TD>-->
   </TR>
   </TABLE>
  <TABLE id="dataTable" width="740px" border="1"> 
   <tr>
   <TD width="32"> 1 </TD>
   <td width="171" ><div>
      <input id="weight1" type="text" name="weight1" placeholder="00.000" 
 autofocus="autofocus">
 </div> </td>

  <td width="171" ><div>
  <input  id="length1" placeholder="000.00" type="text" name="length1"> </div></td>

  <td width="171" ><div>
  <input  id="width1" placeholder="000.00" type="text" name="width1"> </div></td>

  <td width="171" ><div>
  <input  id="height1" placeholder="000.00" type="text" name="height1"> </div></td>

  <td width="171" ><div>
  <button id="opener">Open Dialog</button> </div></td>
  </tr>
  </TABLE>

</div>
<INPUT name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Get Quotes">
</form>
```

dialog content

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
Weight<input type="text" id="wt" name="weight"  title="Weight"/>
Length<input type="text" id="lgt" name="length"  title="Length"/>
Width<input type="text" id="wdt" name="width"  title="Width"/> 
Height<input type="text" id="ht" name="height"  title="Height"/>
<ul id="categories">
  <li id="cat-1">
  <img src="Images/download.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" 
onclick="PopulateDetails(1,1,1,1)">

  </li>
  <li id="cat-2">
   <img src="Images/Fedex_express.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" 
onclick="PopulateDetails(2,2,2,2)">
  </li>
  <li id="cat-3">
   <img src="Images/download.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" 
onclick="PopulateDetails(3,3,3,3)">
  </li>
  <li id="cat-4">
   <img src="Images/Fedex_express.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" 
onclick="PopulateDetails(4,4,4,4)">
  </li>
</ul>
<button name="OK" onclick="PopulateForm()">OK</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Prevent the default form submission:

```
$( "#opener" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form gets submitted on clicking open dialog..

try adding return false.

```
    $( "#opener" ).click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
```

for the each row update part. you can make it simpler..

Add a id to each Table row

on clicking opener. get the parent TR's "id" attribute and substr to get the row ID.

on hitting "OK" from the popup dialog. update the input fields from the TR#ID

Comment: the code in your function "PopulateForm" will be complicated or may not work if there is more than 1 row in your table

Comment: @popnoodles, Agreed!, but in this case there will be no issue

Comment: You don't know there will be no issue. How can you be so sure that there won't be an event bound to an element higher up that performs a less obvious task when it receives that bubbled-up click event?

Comment: I had read his question and what all hs requirement was :)
and the link you provide states that return false called 3 code .
preventDefault (we can do this), stopPropogation

and return false will exit the callback. (no harm)

Comment: Ok I get that. But you can't see that something won't be added in the future. My coding isn't perfect but there are pitfalls you can avoid and `return false` is one of them.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<title>title</title>


<script>
$(function() {
 $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
  alert("ok");
  return false;
 });
 $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
  alert("ok2 poop");
  return false;
 });
});  

</script>


<a href="#" id="opener">Click Me</a>


I see my both event got triggered

Comment: I'm wasting my time trying to educate you.

Comment: I am using js to add the the rows dynamically to the table. The id  'opener' is not working to populate the dynamically generated rows.